# How get the attributes of "this"?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, this

I'm trying to make a event listener, as detailed [here](http://bl.ocks.org/WilliamQLiu/76ae20060e19bf42d774). For this, I'm analyzing the `this` construct. When adding a point in the given link, and adding the line

```
  console.log(this);
```

in the `handleMouseOver` event handler, `this` yields the element (for example)

```
  <circle cx="231 cy="333" r="6" fill="black"></circle>
```

I now wish to select one of these attributes in order to control the behaviour. How could I select (for example), the `cx` attribute? I've tried

```
this.attr('cx')
```

without no success.
Thanks for all input!

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is simple Dom node. You can use:

```
this.getAttribute( 'cx' );
```

or

```
d3.select( this ).attr( 'cx' );
```